# pandas to_sql creates empty tables, can't replace tables

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I've got mysql and pandas, trying to insert dataframes into mysql as tables. The code below inserts an empty table and than can't replace it.I'm using Python 3.10, used pip install mysqlclient to get mysqldb module. What's wrong? What's the fix?

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from Modules import connect
from sqlalchemy.orm import close_all_sessions

df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((3, 3)))
df.columns=['a','b','c']

con_=connect.local_connect(login,password,database)
df.to_sql(name='name',con=con_,if_exists='replace',index=False)
close_all_sessions()
```

after running the code once:

```
mysql> select * from name;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

after running the the second time it gets stuck, when I check the processlist :

```
mysql> show processlist;
+----+-----------------+-----------------+------+---------+------+---------------------------------+------------------+
| Id | User            | Host            | db   | Command | Time | State                           | Info             |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+------+---------+------+---------------------------------+------------------+
|  5 | event_scheduler | localhost       | NULL | Daemon  |  768 | Waiting on empty queue          | NULL             |
| 11 | root            | localhost:10003 | database | Sleep   |  146 |                                 | NULL             |
| 13 | root            | localhost:10839 | database | Query   |    0 | init                            | show processlist |
| 14 | root            | localhost:12673 | database | Query   |    2 | Waiting for table metadata lock | DROP TABLE name |
+----+-----------------+-----------------+------+---------+------+---------------------------------+------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have to clarify what data type is your dataset by the parameter dtype in the .to_sql() method, in my case I have put it as int as the whole data set is numbers.
if there is more than one type, you can make a dictionary with names of columns as keys and data types as values and put it as an argument for the dtype parameter.
Note: the data types are sql not python and for that you can install the types module from sqlalchemy and specify the sql types you want.